# python compute pct_change() from last value of the previous month

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to compute returns from last value of the previous month, here is the sample dataframe, daily value. I can't figure out how to achieve this with pct_change() functio

**Sample df**

```
date        value     
31/07/2020  141.793,00
03/08/2020  145.401,00 
04/08/2020  124.534,00 
05/08/2020  147.562,00
06/08/2020  131.043,00
07/08/2020  132.556,00
10/08/2020  140.874,00
11/08/2020  128.603,00
01/09/2020  131.451,00
02/09/2020  137.862,00
03/09/2020  130.439,00
04/09/2020  124.608,00
07/09/2020  133.674,00
08/09/2020  126.454,00
09/09/2020  136.488,00
```

**Goal**

I need to compute the current monthly cumulated return for each day. The return value for the day should be the return from the last value of the previous month. Something like this:

```
date        value        monthly
31/07/2020  141.793,00           NaN
03/08/2020  145.401,00   0,025445544
04/08/2020  124.534,00   -0,12171969
05/08/2020  147.562,00   0,040686071
06/08/2020  131.043,00  -0,075814744
07/08/2020  132.556,00   -0,06514426
10/08/2020  140.874,00  -0,006481279
11/08/2020  128.603,00  -0,093022928
01/09/2020  131.451,00   0,022145673
02/09/2020  137.862,00   0,071996765
03/09/2020  130.439,00   0,014276494
04/09/2020  124.608,00  -0,031064594
07/09/2020  133.674,00   0,039431429
08/09/2020  126.454,00  -0,016710341
09/09/2020  136.488,00   0,061312722
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get what you need with the following.

Use `str.replace` to replace the `,` , then convert to `float`, and then apply `pct_change()` and return a new column:

```
df['monthly'] = df['value'].str.replace(',','').astype(float).pct_change()
```

which prints:

```
                   date       value   monthly
0            31/07/2020  141.793,00       NaN
1   2020-03-08 00:00:00  145.401,00  0.025446
2   2020-04-08 00:00:00  124.534,00 -0.143513
3   2020-05-08 00:00:00  147.562,00  0.184913
4   2020-06-08 00:00:00  131.043,00 -0.111946
5   2020-07-08 00:00:00  132.556,00  0.011546
6   2020-10-08 00:00:00  140.874,00  0.062751
7   2020-11-08 00:00:00  128.603,00 -0.087106
8   2020-01-09 00:00:00  131.451,00  0.022146
9   2020-02-09 00:00:00  137.862,00  0.048771
10  2020-03-09 00:00:00  130.439,00 -0.053844
11  2020-04-09 00:00:00  124.608,00 -0.044703
12  2020-07-09 00:00:00  133.674,00  0.072756
13  2020-08-09 00:00:00  126.454,00 -0.054012
14  2020-09-09 00:00:00  136.488,00  0.079349
```